# ARGB Fans are not working after Installing Ubuntu Alongside Windows

Tags: dual-boot, fan, temperature

My PC came prebuilt and the ARGB lighted chassis fans worked fine; I was able to control fan curves and set lighting. After installing Ubuntu alongside Windows in a dual boot setup  I cannot control the fans/lights from either operating system. Even BIOS says N/A.

The RGB lights on my AIO cooler are detected and controllable but AIO cooler also says N/A. One fan runs constantly after my tinkering.

no running 'pwmconfig' declares:

```
/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

I ran `sensors-detect` and `sensors` which gave me:

```
nvme-pci-0200
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +41.9°C  (low  =  -0.1°C, high = +74.8°C)
                       (crit = +79.8°C)
ERROR: Can't get value of subfeature temp2_min: I/O error
ERROR: Can't get value of subfeature temp2_max: I/O error
Sensor 1:     +51.9°C  (low  =  +0.0°C, high =  +0.0°C)
ERROR: Can't get value of subfeature temp3_min: I/O error
ERROR: Can't get value of subfeature temp3_max: I/O error
Sensor 2:     +33.9°C  (low  =  +0.0°C, high =  +0.0°C)
ERROR: Can't get value of subfeature temp4_min: I/O error
ERROR: Can't get value of subfeature temp4_max: I/O error
Sensor 3:     +41.9°C  (low  =  +0.0°C, high =  +0.0°C)**
```

I believe these correspond to the three fans not working, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: please post the output of `sensors-detect`